# Enthought InstanceEditor Demo Raises TraitError

Tags: python, python-3.x, enthought, traitsui

The InstanceEditor demo example at [Enthought GitHub Repository](https://github.com/enthought/traitsui/blob/master/examples/demo/Standard_Editors/InstanceEditor_demo.py) raises the following exception:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jgv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\traitsui\ui.py", line 232, in dispose
    self.result = result
  File "C:\Users\jgv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\traits\trait_handlers.py", line 172, in error
    value )
traits.trait_errors.TraitError: The 'result' trait of an UI instance must be a boolean, but a value of <PyQt4.QtCore.QObject object at 0x000001EA249AEB88> <class 'PyQt4.QtCore.QObject'> was specified.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jgv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\traitsui\ui.py", line 232, in dispose
    self.result = result
  File "C:\Users\jgv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\traits\trait_handlers.py", line 172, in error
    value )
traits.trait_errors.TraitError: The 'result' trait of an UI instance must be a boolean, but a value of <PyQt4.QtCore.QObject object at 0x000001EA249AEB88> <class 'PyQt4.QtCore.QObject'> was specified.
```

when the user interface is used to specify a trait setting.

My system is: Python 3.6.0, traits 4.6.0, PyQt4-4.11.4, and Microsoft Windows 10.

I would appreciate suggestions on how to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please file at https://github.com/enthought/traitsui/issues

Answer (score 1):

For the record: issue filed and being discussed at https://github.com/enthought/traitsui/issues/331